# Scatterplot alternatives power bi

Tags: powerbi, scatter-plot

I have a report with multiple visuals.
At the moment i am using multiple scatterplots to visualize data.

The scatterplot is ideal for visualizing my data as it bring usefull insight.
However I am not a fan of the amount of scatterplots I am using as it makes the report kinda busy.

So, are there any alternatives to the scatterplots that would provide me with the same insight?

Please see the image for my report (don't mind how it looks, i have not done a lot of styling yet as this is a first stage test report)

As you could perhaps see I used Conditional formatting in my scatterplots, so for alternatives i would like to still be able to do this (if possible)
[image]

example for a scatterplot:
 i am showing coverage on the x-axis and the Workforce + retired on the y axis.

For all my scatterplots I am filtering the following:

- I am filtering for year and quartile for date
- I am filtering for different type of fund, i.e what type of fund a fund belongs to
- for conditional formatting I am using a specific fund

Comment: This would be a better fit for StackExchange Data Science as it's off topic here.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, i'll post my question there!